# Using TaskDialogIndirect in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, interop

I've been working for a while with the regular Windows Vista/7 TaskDialog for a while, and I wanted to add some additional functionality (like custom buttons and a footer), so I need to use [TaskDialogIndirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Following the MSDN documentation for TaskDialogIndirect, I got this signature:

```
[DllImport("comctl32.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,EntryPoint="TaskDialogIndirect")]
static extern int TaskDialogIndirect (TASKDIALOGCONFIG pTaskConfig, out int pnButton, out int pnRadioButton, out bool pfVerificationFlagChecked);
```

The [TASKDIALOGCONFIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787473%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class is shown below:

```
public class TASKDIALOGCONFIG
{
    public UInt16 cbSize;
    public IntPtr hwndParent;
    public IntPtr hInstance;
    public String dwFlags;
    public String dwCommonButtons;
    public IntPtr hMainIcon;
    public String pszMainIcon;
    public String pszMainInstruction;
    public String pszContent;
    public UInt16 cButtons;
    public TASKDIALOG_BUTTON pButtons;
    public int nDefaultButton;
    public UInt16 cRadioButtons;
    public TASKDIALOG_BUTTON pRadioButtons;
    public int nDefaultRadioButton;
    public String pszVerificationText;
    public String pszExpandedInformation;
    public String pszExpandedControlText;
    public String pszCollapsedControlText;
    public IntPtr hFooterIcon;
    public IntPtr pszFooterText;
    public String pszFooter;
    // pfCallback;
    // lpCallbackData;
    public UInt16 cxWidth;
}
```

The TASKDIALOG_BUTTON implementation:

```
public class TASKDIALOG_BUTTON
{
    public int nButtonID;
    public String pszButtonText;
}
```

I am not entirely sure if I am on the right track here. Did anyone use TaskDialogIndirect from managed code directly through WinAPI (without VistaBridge or Windows API Code Pack)? I am curious about the possible implementations, as well as the callback declarations (I am not entirely sure how to implement [TaskDialogCallbackProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760542%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)).

**PS:** I am looking for a direct WinAPI implementation, not one through a wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth looking through the Windows API code pack source code as it contains a reasonably complete implementation of TaskDialogIndirect using WinAPI - including callbacks - which would be a good starting point for your own implementation.

Comment: I did look through it, but being a wrapper, it contains a lot of additional code that is not needed in my case. What I am trying to do is, at this point, to create a simple Task Dialog with some custom actions.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the VistaBridge library. It will give you a pleasant wrapper around all this stuff, including TaskDialogIndirect..

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge

Comment: I am looking for a direct WinAPI implementation. A wrapper is nice, however I am trying to "look under the hood" and build the call from scratch.

Comment: @Dennis fair enough, still though if you download the above library you will get to see how it's done, all the source code is there.

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21276/Vista-TaskDialog-Wrapper-and-Emulator. Specifically the file VistaUnsafeNativeMethods.cs has the relevant `DllImport` bits, including `VistaTaskDialogCallback` which I think is the callback you are interested in.

Answer (score -1):

[PInvoke.NET](http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx) is a great resource for PInvoke techniques.  Unfortunately, they only have a TODO stub for [TaskDialogIndirect](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comctl32/TaskDialogIndirect.html) so far.

Comment: Exactly. This is why I started this research.

Comment: The callback should be a delegate.  Since it's all in params, it should be fairly straightforward.  Look at the PInvoke.NET declaration of EnumFontFamilyExProc for comparison:  http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Delegates.EnumFontFamExProc

Comment: The [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comctl32/TaskDialogIndirect.html) page on PInvoke.net was filled in with full details earlier this year.